# How do I run my Django testcase multiple times?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-unittest

I want to perform some exhaustive testing against one of my test-cases (say, create a document, to debug some weird things I am encountering..)

My brutal force was to fire `python manage.py test myapp` in a loop either using `Popen` or `os.system`, but now I am back to pure way ?.....

```
def SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):

   def test_01(self):

   def tearDown(self):

def suite():
   suite = unittest.TestCase()
   suite.add(SimpleTest("setUp"))
   suite.add(SimpleTest("test_01"))
   suite.add(SimpleTest("tearDown"))
   return suite

def main():
   for i in range(n):
     suite().run("runTest")
```

I ran `python manage.py test myapp` and I got

```
  File "/var/lib/system-webclient/webclient/apps/myapps/tests.py", line 46, in suite
    suite = unittest.TestCase()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 216, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName)
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unittest.TestCase'>: runTest
```

I've googled the error, but I still clueless (I was told to add an empty runTest method, but that doesn't sound right at all...)

Well, according to python's `unittest.TestCase`:

> The simplest TestCase subclass will simply override the runTest()
>   method in order to perform specific testing code

As you can see, my whole goal is to run my `SimpleTest` N times. I need to keep track of pass, failure against N.

What option do I have?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of running it more than once?  Are you looking for race conditions?

Comment: @AlexLebedev Yes, I believe that's my intention. I came across this "mysterious error" which occurs occasionally. I want to provide that it has nothing to do with the network. I understand this is not a fair unit-test. According to the documentation, I think there is a way to tell how many is okay and how many fails after a test. But I am not sure whether there is a right way to do what I want or not.

Comment: Would [parameterized.expand](https://github.com/wolever/parameterized) help?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking race conditions via unit tests is tricky.  Sometimes you're better off hitting your frontend with automated testing tool like Selenium -- unlike unit test, environment is the same and there's no need for extra work to ensure concurrency.  Here's one way to run concurrent code in tests when there're no better option: http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/05/26/testing-django-views-for-concurrency-issues/

Just keep in mind that concurrent test is no definite proof you're free from race conditions -- there's no guarantee it'll recreate all possible combinations of execution order among processes.